# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n^3}{\log (n^3+3n^2)}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I want to solve this
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log n^3}{\log \left(n^3+3n^2\right)}$$
I found that 
$$ \frac{\log n^3}{\log \left(n^3+3n^2\right)}<\frac{\log\left( n^3\right)}{\log \left(n^3\right)}=1$$
but I need another bond according to the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3\ln n}{3\ln n+\ln\left(1+\dfrac3n\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3}{3+\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac3n\right)}{\ln n}}=?$$

Comment: bhattacharje really I can't understand

Comment: @Anne, $$\ln(n^a)=a\ln n$$ right?

Comment: I can't understand the chamgements in the denominator

Comment: @Anne, Divided numerator & denominator by $\ln n$

Comment: ahh ok now I see...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you use *equivalents*, it's obvious: $\;n^3+3n^2\sim_\infty n^3$, so 
$$\log(n^3+3n^2)\sim_\infty\log n^3,\quad\text{and finally }\;\frac{\log n^3}{\log(n^3+3n^2)}\sim_\infty\frac{\log n^3}{\log n^3}=1.$$